# Rails Time Form Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I currently have a form that uses `select_date Date.today` When I view the form I can select options such as January 3, 2012.  Although when I post the value, it reads `2013-01-03 00:00:00`

In the create action the parameters for the Show's date is as followed:

```
@show.date = Date.civil(params[:date][:year].to_i, 
                        params[:date][:month].to_i, 
                        params[:date][:day].to_i)
```

How might I get this to read as it read when I selected the date, aka "January 3, 2013"?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show the view code?

Comment: the view is just the generic show.date in the _show partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer is to call [`date.strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) passing in the format string `"%B %d, %Y"` wherever you want to *display* the date. (You can use `"%B %-d, %Y"` if you don't want `day` to be zero-padded):

```
Show: <%= date.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %>
```

Comment: Hi, I am sorry it took so long for a response.  I had an unexpected leave.  This worked perfectly, thank you!